# Issue getting API data to show in web browser using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, axios

I am trying to create a trivia game using React.js Typescript and The Trivia API. I am transferring data through components using useContext, and am navigating through components using react-router-dom. When I move from the Category Spinning Wheel to the question, I am not seeing any text from the question. Any help would be appreciated!

This is the Spin Wheel component:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import PlayerContext from '../context/PlayerContext';
import TriviaAPI from '../services/TriviaAPI';
import '../styles/CategorySpinWheel.css';
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export default function CategorySpinWheel() {
    interface Category {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        class: string;
        uri: string
      }

      const navigate = useNavigate();

      const{currentQuestion, pastQuestions, score, hearts, difficulty, resetCurrentQuestion, pushPastQuestions, resetScore, addScore, resetHearts, deleteHeart, resetDifficulty} = useContext(PlayerContext);
      
      const categories: Category[] = [
        { id: 1, name: 'GENERAL KNOWLEDGE', class: "general-knowledge-spin", uri: "general_knowledge" },
        { id: 2, name: 'GEOGRAPHY', class: "geography-spin", uri: "geography" },
        { id: 3, name: 'FILM & TV', class: "film-tv-spin" , uri: "film_and_tv"},
        { id: 4, name: 'HISTORY', class: "history-spin", uri: "history" },
        { id: 5, name: 'MUSIC', class: "music-spin", uri: "music" },
        { id: 6, name: 'FOOD & DRINK', class: "food-drink-spin", uri: "food_and_drink" },
        { id: 7, name: 'SCIENCE', class: "science-spin", uri: "science" },
        { id: 8, name: 'ARTS & LITERATURE', class: "arts-literature-spin", uri: "arts_and_literature" },
        { id: 9, name: 'SPORT & LEISURE', class: "sport-leisure-spin", uri: "sport_and_leisure" },
        { id: 10, name: 'SOCIETY & CULTURE', class: "society-culture-spin", uri: "society_and_culture" }
      ];
      
    const [screen, setScreen] = useState("spin");

    const [spinResult, setSpinResult] = useState<Category | null>(null);
    const [isSpinning, setIsSpinning] = useState(false);
    const [randomCategoryClass, setRandomCategoryClass] = useState<string>("");
    const [spinButtonVisible, setSpinButtonVisible] = useState(true);

    const spinWheel = () => {
      setIsSpinning(true);
      const randomCategory = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
      TriviaAPI(randomCategory.uri, difficulty).then(data => {
        resetCurrentQuestion(data);
      })
      setRandomCategoryClass(randomCategory.class);
      setTimeout(() => {
          setSpinResult(randomCategory);
          setIsSpinning(false);
          setScreen("chosen");
      }, 6000);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
            <p>Hearts</p>
            <p>Score: 200</p>
        </div>
        <h2>CATEGORY SPIN WHEEL</h2>
        <div id="wheel-div">
          <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/wheel.png'} alt="spinning image" className={`${randomCategoryClass} wheel`} />
          <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/WheelArrow.png'} alt="spinning image" className='wheel-arrow'/>
        </div>
        {
          spinButtonVisible && 
          <button onClick={() => {
            setSpinButtonVisible(false);
            spinWheel();
          }
          }>SPIN</button>
        }
      </div>
      {
        screen === "chosen" &&
        <div className='picked-screen'>
          <p>Your category is:</p>
          <p>{spinResult?.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => {
            setScreen("spin");
            setRandomCategoryClass("");
            setSpinButtonVisible(true);
            navigate('/question');
          }}>GO TO QUESTION</button>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the question component:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import PlayerContext from '../context/PlayerContext'

export default function Question() {
    const{currentQuestion, pastQuestions, score, hearts, difficulty, resetCurrentQuestion, pushPastQuestions, resetScore, addScore, resetHearts, deleteHeart, resetDifficulty} = useContext(PlayerContext);
    let wrongAnswers = currentQuestion?.incorrectAnswers;
    let answers = [currentQuestion?.correctAnswer];
    for (let i = answers.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [answers[i], answers[j]] = [answers[j], answers[i]];
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{currentQuestion?.category}</h1>
        <p>{currentQuestion?.question}</p>
        {answers.map(answer => 
            <button>{answer}</button>
        )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is the context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export interface Question{
    "category": string,
    "id": string,
    "correctAnswer": string,
    "incorrectAnswers": string[],
    "question": string,
    "difficulty": string
}

export interface PlayerContextModel{
    currentQuestion: Question | null;
    pastQuestions: Question[];
    score: number,
    hearts: number,
    difficulty: string,
    resetCurrentQuestion: (question: Question) => void,
    pushPastQuestions: (question: Question) => void,
    resetScore: () => void,
    addScore: () => void,
    resetHearts: () => void,
    deleteHeart: () => void,
    resetDifficulty: (diff: string) => void
}

const defaultValue: PlayerContextModel = {
    currentQuestion: null,
    pastQuestions: [],
    score: 0,
    hearts: 0,
    difficulty: "easy",
    resetCurrentQuestion: () => {},
    pushPastQuestions: () => {},
    resetScore: () => {},
    addScore:() => {},
    resetHearts:() => {},
    deleteHeart:() => {},
    resetDifficulty:() => {}
}

const PlayerContext = createContext(defaultValue);
export default PlayerContext;
```

This is the context provider:

```
import React, {ReactNode, useState, useContext} from 'react'
import { Question } from './PlayerContext';
import PlayerContext from './PlayerContext';

interface Props {children: ReactNode; }

export default function PlayerContextProvider({children}: Props) {
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState<Question | null>(null);
    const [pastQuestions, setPastQuestions] = useState<Question[]>([])
    const [score, setScore] = useState<number>(0);
    const [hearts, setHearts] = useState<number>(0);
    const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState<string>("easy");
    function resetCurrentQuestion(question: Question): void {
        setCurrentQuestion(question)
    }
    function pushPastQuestions(question: Question): void {
        setPastQuestions(prev => [...prev, question]);
    }
    function resetScore(): void {
        setScore(0);
    }
    function addScore(): void {
        setScore(score + 100);
    }
    function resetHearts(): void {
        setHearts(0);
    }
    function deleteHeart(): void {
        setHearts(hearts - 1);
    }
    function resetDifficulty(diff: string): void {
        setDifficulty(diff);
    }
  return (
    <PlayerContext.Provider value={{currentQuestion, pastQuestions, score, hearts, difficulty, resetCurrentQuestion, pushPastQuestions, resetScore, addScore, resetHearts, deleteHeart, resetDifficulty}}>
        {children}
    </PlayerContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And this is the service I am using to get the API Data:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Question } from "../context/PlayerContext";

export default function TriviaAPI(category: string, difficulty: string): Promise<Question> {
  return axios
    .get<Question>(`https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions?categories=${category}&limit=1&difficulty=${difficulty}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but in the service file, you're not transforming the data to JSON, which might be the issue. Also, try to put your code in a [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or something similar, state what you tried & what is the exact problem. It's hard to just look at & read blocks of code w/o any context to find the problem.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console or the server? Does the request return successfully in the network tab? Does Context look right in React dev tools?

Comment: Is `currentQuestion` an array of 1 question and instead should be the first element of the array? Try returning `res.data[0]` in `TriviaAPI()`.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli I think I figured code sandbox out, here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/AndrewDamas/AndrewsTrivia/main?workspaceId=8e13f390-dcf8-4ab2-85a2-321b31b34a07&file=%2FREADME.md
How would I go about transforming the data to JSON?

Comment: @JBallin That was it! it was returning an array. I just assumed since it was only returning one object that it wouldn't be in an array. Had to add [0] to res.data and had to change a variable type and that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.data` is an array, use `res.data[0]` to get the (first) question itself.